# Apache - Mapping url to local path for static content

Tags: apache, url, static

My httpd.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ...
    DocumentRoot /home/www/static
    ...
    <Directory /home/www/static>
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
    </Directory>

    <Location "/foo">
    SetHandler None
    </Location>
</virtualhost>
```

I have a file at /home/www/static/foo/helloworld.txt. And if I go to http://localhost/foo/helloworld.txt I will see that file.

Now, for some irrelevant reason, I want to change the urls. The above url should return nothing, while http://localhost/bar/helloworld.txt should return the file. And I want to achieve this, without changing anything in the directory structure.

How is that done?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use `Alias` to map different url paths to filesystem paths:

```
Alias /bar /home/www/static/foo
```

See  http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#alias for more info.

Comment: Or you can create a symbolic link `bar` points to `/home/www/static/foo`