# URL without extension like http://store.apple.com/us

Tags: url-rewriting

How can I use this structure. Here is an example of what I mean: [image: Example]

It doesn't have .html or .php or a "/" at the end.

I have been using this structure: http://s0ulp1xel.x10.mx/?p=home

What is the URL type called?

Comment: One way of achieving this is using rewrite/alias rules in apache - that would be a good place to start your research

Comment: possible duplicate of [How come some site urls do not include a file extension?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3631153/how-come-some-site-urls-do-not-include-a-file-extension)

Comment: The URL type is called "URL". There's nothing special about it. What you need to do is to redirect requests to that URL to your script. This is fiddlier to do in PHP than on other platforms because of its source-file-based deployment model, you need to handle this at the web server level. In Apache, you use [`mod_rewrite`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html), but I'm not really familiar with it enough to provide details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for a URL *alias*:

[Apache - Mapping url to local path for static content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6736786/apache-mapping-url-to-local-path-for-static-content)

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/urlmapping.html

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#alias

Answer (score 0):

URLs don’t necessarily refer to specific files. For example, in Node.js, you can create a server that responds to any page:

```
http.createServer(function(request, response) {
    response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    response.end('You’ve reached the Node.js server!');
}).listen(80, '0.0.0.0');
```

… but in PHP with Apache, you’re probably looking for aliases and/or rewrites! For example:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^page/(\d+)$ page.php?id=$1
```

would rewrite a URL like `http://example.com/page/5` to `http://example.com/page.php?id=5`.

And in this particular case, you could use the directory structure `/us/index.php`